# Show first name in mail body

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have created workflow using SPD2010 and used action 'send an email'.
In email body I want to show user 'First name + Last name' like "Hi Brishal Kumar" for this I have set it 'current item[created by]'

let me know what I need to do.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a couple of simple steps to overcome that problem.

- Create a new workflow in SharePoint Designer
- Insert Send an Email action and then click These Users link
- In the Define E-mail message field type your desired email body text and click Add or Change Lookup
- In the Lookup for String dialog
- Select User Profiles as Data source
- Field from source: Name
- In the Find the List Item, select Account Name as field and then filter by Current Item: Created By (or Modified By, or some other Person column, or any other column that contains username)

[source](http://www.sharepointusecases.com/index.php/2013/04/display-full-name-in-sharepoint-designer-workflows/)

Comment: it is giving me below error:  

Workflow failed to get user profile for user ..

Answer (score 1):

Please find screenshot below that should help.

You can choose from drop down  "Return Field as:" to show login name or display name.
Select " Display Name " who will display the full name of the user. If several users, use " Display name, Semicolon Delimited "

[image]

Comment: Not able to see screenshot

Comment: i m trying to add screenshot.. but don't why its not visible.. i have flaged the post.

Comment: @KunalValecha The sceenshot is there. Maybe your firewall is preventing the image URL? Brows to http://i.stack.imgur.com/NVoJN.png and see what you get there.

Comment: on browsing this url also i am not able to see screen shot.. where should i look in to resolve this problem ?

Comment: I am also not able to see screenshot

Comment: Clearly visible here to!